# Understanding the mechanism of a chain of methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, apollo-client, apollo-link

I do not understand this for both redux-middleware and apollo-links. How all these functions are executed in sequence and then pass the context to each other
Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the Observer pattern.
In this pattern, we have an entity (called a subject) that several other entities listen to without knowing how it works (called an observer).
As soon as the subject changes, all observers are notified and perform a special operation based on this change.
In apollo-link, by defining each link, you generate an independent observerable that listens for apollo-client operation changes.

[image]